# Errors trying to Sort a datagrid (XAML / C#)

Tags: c#, datagrid

should be a simple problems but i can't find a fix. I get these errors in my c#:

> 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'Sort' and no extension method 'Sort' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and

> 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'Ascending' and no extension method 'Ascending' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here's my code:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="5" Margin="0 0 25 0"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="studentData" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

C#:

```
private void sortByName_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        studentDataGrid.ItemsSource = studentClass;
        studentDataGrid.Sort(studentDataGrid.Columns[0], studentDataGrid.Ascending);
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any xaml that you can show for the datagrid?

Comment: Sorry was meant to add that `<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="5" Margin="0 0 25 0"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="studentData" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGrid` doesn't have `Sort` method. There [are](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/5d3942c8-e3e1-4284-b1b3-0b8b94150d86/) a [lot](http://dotnetgui.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/how-to-properly-sort-on-wpf-datagrid.html) of blog posts and articles on how to apply a sort to a datagrid in code.

Comment: Thanks, although I'm still having 1 problem...
How do I create a ListSortDirection? I'm trying `ListSortDirection direction = Ascending;` but it says `The name 'Ascending' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: It's [Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.listsortdirection.aspx) `ListSortDirection direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;`